# php laravel 5.2.20 send smtp mail

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I want send smtp mail in laravel 5.2.20 in php
 But i am getting this error

```
  Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 ra1sm17783395pab.24 - gsmtp
"
```

My config/mail.php file:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'example@gmail.com', 'name' => 'example'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('example@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('example_pwd'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

This is my laravel 5.2.20 framework mail.php but i don't update anything in my .env file. In my laravel framework Dotenv.php file is their but .env is not here. Which one i need to update....

My controller code is below here:

```
$user = Users::findOrFail($id);

Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($user->email);
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($user->name);
    //exit;
    $m->from('example@gmail.com', 'Your Application');

    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ther error  `Authentication Required`.
You need to put your username and password for SMTP settings, put them in `.env` file if you dont have one create it

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=your_SMTP HOST
MAIL_PORT=YOUR SMTP PORT
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```